# Android: starActivityForResult and Fragment issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a simple question for you:

If `starActivityForResult()` is called in an Activity, `onActivityResult()` is called back only in that Activity and NOT in the attached Fragments;

If `starActivityForResult()` is called in a Fragment attached to an Activity, `onActivityResult()` is called back in the Activity AND in the Fragment itself;

It is correct? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No. It's either the activity or the fragment, not both.

Evidence: [`dispatchActivityResult()` in `Activity`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#5416).